# How to set view outlet for a UIViewController that contains a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, interface-builder

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITabbarController which contains a UINavigationController.

When I am setting up my IB outlets, what should the File's Owner view outlet be set to?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be set to UITabbarController. Later, if you need to access to UINavigationController just call like this [tabBar.navigationController pushViewController:animated];

Comment: IB won't let me set the File Owner's view to the UITabBarController, only the tab-bar part of it. The proper outlets are defined in my header file.